# (1/2), (a/b) I'd like to know which sentence is the best choice

Tags: sentence-construction

**There is a time when I drink too much to hang out with my friends**

> 1. until they think they drink enough to call it a night.
> 2. as much as they'd like to.

I think both are possible to use and natural.

**I always end up being the only one who has to go home**

> a. because I'm too drunk to be with others.
>
> b. because of being too drunk to be with others.

I think b is better because it is not mentioning a specific person who is too drunk, so it is more of a general sentence than a sentence illustrating my situation.

Comment: I think to prevent this from closing, you need to provide your share of thoughts and the context more elaborately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to say with the first sentence, it seems like 1 and 2 are not saying the same thing at all. I would phrase the sentence differently:

> I drink too much to hang out with my friends as much as they'd like
>   (me to).

This is saying you have a drinking problem that's affecting your social life. The (me to) isn't necessary here, but could be added. You can't say "there is a time" or "sometimes" or reference any particular time, since you're talking about a habitual, ongoing condition of your friends wanting to hang out with you. If you want to use choice 1 (which means something entirely different), you could say:

> Sometimes I drink too much to hang out with my friends until they have
>   drunk enough to call it a night.

This sentence says you sometimes get too drunk too quickly when you go out with your friends and can't finish the evening with them - it's happened a few times, but not all the time. You use sometimes here because you are talking about particular (though unspecified) occasions. You also leave out the "they think" because it's implied that they are the ones deciding when they've had enough. If it were different, you could say for example "until the bartender thinks they have drunk enough", because someone else is making that decision.

For the second sentence, choice a) is definitely better. Here, you ARE talking about a specific person that's too drunk, which is you.

Comment: I think you are right that "there is a time" can be used to specify a time. then how about " there are times when I drink too much"? I think it means pretty much the same as sometimes.

Comment: Yes, that works fine. With both you're referring some indeterminate number of unspecified occurrences.